# Adaptive card not displaying after publishing cortana channel

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-intelligence

I have developed a simple application in web app bot which includes a Welcome Adaptive card. When i tested it in emulator it is working fine but adaptive card is not working after I published and it says something went wrong.

Comment: Which Cortana client are you using (Windows, Android, etc.)? Can you provide any of your code, especially the Adaptive Card JSON? And when you say it's a "Welcome" Adaptive Card, do you mean you want Cortana to send it to the user before the user has sent a message? ConversationUpdate isn't available in all channels.

Comment: If this is a cortana skill, make sure debug is turned on and post the response json here.  "Something went wrong" can be anything, for example, the endpoint is misconfigured, there was a timeout, or there is a glitch in invocation (anything in the web app bot logs?)

Comment: @KyleDelaney i am using windows cortana client, yes I want cortana to send adaptive card before user sent a message. Can you please tell me what you mean by " Conversation Update isn't available in all channels".

Comment: ConversationUpdate is a type of activity that's often used to trigger greeting messages from a bot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#conversationupdate

Comment: Cortana is a channel, and it's up to each channel to decide when and whether they send conversationUpdate activities. The Emulator does send conversationUpdate activities when a user starts a conversation with a bot. But how would this work in Cortana? Your user has to send a message to your Cortana skill before your bot knows it's in a conversation, so when do you imagine your welcome message would be displayed? When Windows starts up?

Comment: Are you still working on this?